# Group by the array value

Tags: php, post, group-by, grouping

I'm using this code:

```
$permissions = array("canview", "canpostthreads", "canpostreplies", "canpostpolls", "all");
foreach($permissions as $permission) {
  for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    $mode = $_POST['permission'][$i][$permission];
    if($mode == 1) 
      echo "{$permission} = {$i}:::";
  }
}
```

And the output if I check some checkboxes is:

```
canview = 1:::canview = 5:::canpostreplies = 3:::canpostpolls = 5:::
```

I wan't the output to be following:

instead of `canview = 1:::canview = 5:`

```
canview = 1,5
```

and if I'll have for example:

```
canpostpolls = 1:::canpostpolls = 2:::canpostpolls = 3
```

It'll be:

```
canpostpolls = 1,2,3:::canview = 1,5
```

I hope you understand it guys. This is my own idea for this, you are free to share your ideas with me, this data will be exported to the mysql table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$permissions = array("canview", "canpostthreads", "canpostreplies", "canpostpolls", "all");
$setpermissions = array();
foreach($permissions as $permission) {
  for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    $mode = $_POST['permission'][$i][$permission];
    if($mode == 1) {
      if (!isset($setpermissions[$permission])) {
         $setpermissions[$permission] = array();
      }
      $setpermissions[$permission][] = $i;
    }
  }
}
$plist = array();
foreach ($setpermissions as $name => $sp) {
   $plist[] = "$name = " . implode(',', $sp);
}
echo implode(':::', $plist);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter your data a bit more... maybe something like this:

```
$permissions = array("canview", "canpostthreads", "canpostreplies", "canpostpolls", "all");
$filtered_perms = array();
foreach($permissions as $permission) {
  for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    $mode = $_POST['permission'][$i][$permission];
    if($mode == 1) {
       if(!is_array($filtered_perms[$permission])) {
         $filtered_perms[$permission] = array();
       }
       $filtered_perms[$permission][] = $i;
  }
}
```

Then, you can do something like:

```
 $final_perms = array();
 foreach($filtered_perms as $key => $val) {
      $final_perms[$key] = implode(",", $val);
  }
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
$permissions = array("canview", "canpostthreads", "canpostreplies", "canpostpolls", "all");
$userPermissions = array();
foreach($permissions as $permission) {
  for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    $mode = $_POST['permission'][$i][$permission];
    if($mode == 1) 
      $userPermissions[$permission][] = $i;
  }
}
foreach($userPermissions as $permission => $values) {
  echo "{$permission} = " . implode(',', $values) . ":::";
}
```

Comment: If you need to remove the `':::'` from the end, instead of `echo` you can save everything to a string and `rtrim(':', $string)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this - essentially, combining the values before outputting them.

```
$permissions = array("canview", "canpostthreads", "canpostreplies", "canpostpolls", "all");
foreach($permissions as $permission) {
  $vals = array();
  for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    $mode = $_POST['permission'][$i][$permission];
    if($mode == 1) 
      $vals[] = $i;
  }
  if(count($vals))
    echo $permission . ' == ' . implode(',', $vals);
}
```